# What are the most common formats that allow interchange of timelines, including footage

Tags: file-formats

The origins on this question are quite similar to [What are the most common project formats for modern NLE software?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12743/what-are-the-most-common-project-formats-for-modern-nle-software) almost ten years ago. If you would edit in an NLE, and want to transfer all assets (maybe not even as an EDL) is there any format that would allow assets to be placed synchronised on multiple tracks relative to each other, without the requirement they have to start at the same time, or render the content?

I am basically looking for a format that would could work with a tool like lossless-cut, in a multi track fashion. And exchange format or container preferably importable by another NLE.